# How to create / find static targeted ads

Tags: advertising, static-content, ad-targeting

I'm not sure how to ask the right question but I noticed on this website, each post has very specific targeted ads that fit the overall theme of the blog post.

www.ma-petite-chou.com

I'm only familiar with google adsense, in which a text box just displays dynamic ads.

I just don't understand how this blog is displaying permanent very specific ads. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, that's a spam blog. It's just post after post after post of affiliate links. So in addition to the loads of ads on the sides, the main content of the blog is advertising.

Secondly, I don't know what you mean by "very specific targeted ads". That site clearly has a single demographic (young asian women), and all the ads are naturally targeted to that demographic. Pretty much any ad network allows you to do that. They're using DoubleClick, but this is standard stuff.

And regardless of whether the ads are static or not, they're not all that targeted beyond what AdSense or any other ad network might give you. Every single page basically just has ads for beauty products and designer clothing. It doesn't take a genius to find a set of 20-30 affiliate/PPC ads for beauty products and designer clothing and include them on every page. It's not like each blog post has distinct content with ads specific to that post only.

Comment: Not only is it all advertising but there's a wish list, too!

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of building your own contextual advertising system (it's not a particularly hard programming task) you might inquire at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

If you are looking for existing apps which accomplish this task, there are a few suggestions at the [How do I implement advertising on my page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/215/how-do-i-implement-advertising-on-my-page) question.*

You should specify which platform you are using (IIS+ASP.net/LAMP/et cetera) to narrow down the suggestions.

*** Google's AdSense *tries* to come up with targeted ads of its own, but it sounds like you want to control the ad content too.